# Oracle - Select statement throwing an error

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select

Please check out this link.

You can see the error message:

[image]

Note : I intentionally kept `roll_no` as a character type.
I need help with the select statement.

Thanks

Comment: Oracle is not mysql, please don't play tag spam. And please post code as text, because that's what it is in reality. We don't want to have to look at a separate picture.   thanks

Comment: Anyway it seems fairly obvious that "Unknown" and "" are not going to be convertible to numbers, so I don't why you would expect TO_NUMBER to work with them. What did you imagine the result would be? What number should "Unknown" be converted to, in your view?

Comment: I have a db which is screwed up. I don't have write access. And I have similar situation where I have a column which should have been in int, but ended up in archer

Comment: And? What's your point? You still can't convert arbitrary text into a number. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: is there any way I can do a cast to that column and get just the numbers in it. I need only numbers present in that column.

Comment: any character value / null present in that column can be converted to 0.

Comment: I just need the values which are truly numbers from that particular column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all your rows will convert to numbers.  `Unknown` and empty string are causing the error.

Comment: I need to extract values which are numbers from the column roll_no . is there any way ? And I don't have write access to this db

Comment: but you have rows where Roll_No is not numeric.. how are you wanting to handle those?  If you want to ignore them then put a WHERE clause in your SELECT, e.g. WHERE Is_Numeric( Roll_No) = 1

Comment: I tried this. it says ORA-00904: "IS_NUMERIC": invalid identifier.

Comment: create table student
(
roll_no varchar(10)
);

insert into student values ('10');
insert into student values ('UnKnown');
insert into student values ('');

select to_number(roll_no) from student
where Is_Numeric( Roll_No) = 1;

Comment: I think you also need to exclude nulls explicitly, WHERE Roll_No IS NOT NULL AND Is_Numeric(Roll_No) = 1, I am a SQL Server guy not sure IS NOT NULL is valid P-SQL

Answer (score 0):

Not everything converts as in your case a null string if you want as some value. place it in the string in the same format like `To_Number('0')`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
select to_number(roll_no) from student
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(roll_no, '^[[:digit:]]+$');
```

Thank you all

Comment: ugh, I personally hate reg exp but glad you were able to move on.